# How show a Div vertically with 100% height and border

Tags: html, css

I have a Div with border that i need to show inside the one of my Div which has width of 100% which contains one logo image and some button .Now as per my requirement i have to show my Second Div with Border and full webpage height just after the last button in the first Div gets ended .Overall My Div with Border should display like Vertical Div with Border from the space remaining in 100% width of first Div till 100% height (Full page) but its not displaying like that.It is getting displayed like Horizontal...Here is the CSS that i have used for First Div...

```
.verticalDiv
{
 position:relative;
 height:auto;
 width:  100%;
}
```

and here is the Fiddle link..[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2moq4t1y/).Please help me to display it correctly in vertical order as explained ..Thanks..

Comment: Are you asking to get the buttons in a vertical line?

Answer (score 0):

Dude if i understand you please check the following

```css
#full{

border:red dashed 2px;
  width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

#small{

border:green dashed 2px;
  width:200px;
    height:400px;

}

button
{
display:block
  
}
```

```html
<div id="full">
  <div id="small">
    this is my left menu :D
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button1</button>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/2moq4t1y/4/

you need to calculate the `height` `100px` is the nav buttons and logo you need to change it the size increases

```
#Computationdiv {
    height: calc(100% - 100px); 
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

and all the `heights` should be `100%`

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

.verticalDiv {
    height:100%;
}
```

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .verticalDiv {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #Computationdiv {
      height: calc(100% - 100px);
      border: 2px solid;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }
    button {
      margin-left: 15px;
      vertical-align: top;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="verticalDiv" class="verticalDiv">
  <img src="img/hotelAwadh.png" alt="logo" />
  <button id="Front Desk">Front Desk</button>
  <button id="Restaurent">Restaurent</button>
  <button id="HouseKeeping">House Keeping</button>
  <button id="TravelDesk">Travel Desk</button>
  <button id="Audit">Audit</button>
  <button id="Report">Report</button>
  <div id="Computationdiv"></div>
</div>
```